# Unique constraint not respected when inserting into SQL table with .NET Core framework

Tags: sql, .net, linq, .net-core, dbcontext

I try to make a register functionality for a REST API in .NET Core 5.
When I create a new user the unique index is not respected and it lets me insert a new user with the same email.

Also, if let's say this constraint would work, what should I get as a result if the insert fails?

```
[Table("users")]
[Index(nameof(Email), IsUnique = true)]
public class UserDAO
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserDAO> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And the code from the Provider that inserts the user(it should return -1 if the insert fails):

```
public int createUser(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth, string email, string password)
{
    UserDAO user = new UserDAO
                       {
                           FirstName = firstName,
                           LastName = lastName,
                           DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth,
                           Email = email,
                           Password = password
                       };

    _dbContext.Users.Add(user);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return user.Id;
}
```

Comment: Does the unique index exist in the database?  Just decorating your entity won't change the database unless you are using Migrations, or you create the database from EF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: I have an inmemory db, the model should be created at runtime. Does that mean that the unique constraint won’t be created while it is still inmemory?

Comment: The In-Memory Provider is intended for testing only, and has many limitations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: In-memory has no DB constraints. Also it is bad idea to test DB functionality using in-memory provider.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I am still learning this framework. Thanks.